# Why my localhost is unable to recognize my htdocs in its directory?

Tags: php, apache, xampp, localhost, htdocs

I have a problem with my XAMPP server after uninstalling an old version for a new one. I have a problem with executing PHP codes because when I put "localhost/file.php" it says "Object not found" or put the PHP document despite having the Apache server on.

When I access the XAMPP directory from localhost, it's completely empty despite I stored the site in the htdocs folder. And if you ask, the xampp folder's location is C:/xampp/. And I did put an .htaccess file in my file's directory.

Here's a screenshot:
[image: my htdocs folder is not there]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving `localhost` in the browser address bar refers to `htdocs` folder.

As we can see the address as `localhost/xampp` i.e you are refering to `htdocs/xampp`

if you have stored your file in `htdocs` root folder, then give the address as `localhost`

Answer (score 2):

xampp -> apache -> config -> apache(httpd.conf) and search DocumentRoot and Directory.
see there what link is set.